# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio: how to turn off the SAVE prompt

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to do this.

I have tried looking through some of the options in the SQL Server Management Studio 2008 but I can't find how to do it, I am sure it is simple.

Can anyone tell me where to turn this off?

Thanks,

EDIT: This is the Prompt that comes up any time you open a new query window , do your stuff and then try to close w/o saving.

Comment: You can't..I believe there is a connect item open for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't turn this off

However, if you want to do something about it, vote for it on connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/308372/permit-nameless-windows-that-do-not-need-saving-in-ssms

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the "Save changes to the following items?" prompt when closing a query window, I think (sadly) the answer is no:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/629405/